# Snowflake environment1 migration to another snowflake environment2

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We are having a Snowflake environment sc01, due to some issues we would like to migrate the sc01 to another environment sc08 and decommission the sc01 environment. All the objects and data need to be migrated from sc01 to sc08.
can someone help me with the points/checklist to look at during this migration?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly large topic, but here are some things to consider when migrating workloads to a different account.

I like to break the items down into two types of categories of Snowflake objects:

- Account Level Objects
- Database Level Objects

"Account Level Objects" are things like users, warehouses, resource monitors, roles, and grants of roles to users.
So, for each of these items, you'll need a strategy/plan in place.

"Database Level Objects" are all the things you'd find inside a database (schemas and their objects like tables, views, UDFs, etc.).
The good news is that Snowflake has a really good replication feature, which allows for databases to be replicated from one account to another, within an Organization.

Assuming your accounts are "Business Critical" or higher, you can use the "failover" feature for each database you have replicated.

docs link:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/replication-failover.html

Note:  not all database objects can be replicated, please see this link to review all schema object types to see if they are able to be included in replication/failover.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/database-replication-intro.html#replicated-database-objects

Other considerations:

- Snowflake has a "Client Redirect" feature which makes this switch more seamless to users:
  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/client-redirect.html
- User's worksheets and contents of their internal stages are not replicated from one account to another.
- Query History and other historical data (warehouse metering, etc.) are not replicated.
- Grants of database objects to roles are currently not replicated, but I believe this is coming soon, so you'll need to also address these grants.

The last point would be of course whatever you do or move forward with, please test/test/test!